# How to create select query to view multiple columns for values?

Tags: sql, oracle, select, view, oracle11g

```
COUNT(DATECREATED)
88708
26625
17092
```

how to create a select query for viewing this three values in single column as different column names like

```
COUNT(DATECREATED)       COUNT(DATECREATED)            COUNT(DATECREATED)
88708                         26625                           17092
88708
88708
```

Comment: COUNT(DATECREATED)
----88708
----26625
--- 17092

Comment: Why `88708` is present thrice and why not `26625`

Comment: COUNT(DATECREATED)       COUNT(DATECREATED)            COUNT(DATECREATED)
88708                         26625                           17092

Comment: Prdp @ i need output like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i did like this.. Thanks all for quick reply

select sum(colname) as aliasname, sum(colname) as aliasname, sum(colname) as aliasname from
(select count(colname) as colname,0 as colname,0 as colname from cof 
union all 
select 0,count(colname),0 from cof where colname is not null
union all
select 0,0,count(colname) from cof where colname is not null);

Answer (score 0):

If you just want 1 row with `3` rows as columns, then use this. Here `col` is the alias for your `count` statement.

```
with tbl as 
(select rownum as rno,col from
    (your existing query) t
)
select (select col from tbl where rno=1) col1 , 
    (select col from tbl where rno=2) col2, 
    (select col from tbl where rno=3 ) col3 
from dual
```

If there are more rows and you want to use them as column, then read about `Dynamic pivot in Oracle` and you shall get your answer.